# How to integrate custom toolbar icon with default toolbar icons

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a table like below with a custom toolbar icon in the top left.
This icon enables/disables the Filter Control.

[image]

It is setup like:

```
  <div id="toolbar">
    <button id="filterable" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <table>
    ..
  </table>
```

Is it possible to integrate this custom icon in the other icons on the right side?
E.g. after the pagination switch icon?

Answer (score 0):

Its currently not possible with the bootstrap-table internal functions.
But there is a [pull request](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/5227) which allows adding custom buttons.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure i understand what you mean, but i alreade included the essential part "its currently not possible".
So the link is only for reference :-)